# Solutionner vs résoudre

Tags: vocabulaire, registre-familier, registre

Je viens de découvrir le verbe *solutionner*, qui m'a paru au premier regard comme une expression familière, voire un anglicisme, mais qui apparemment est [un verbe assez établi en français](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/solutionner).

Existe-t-il des nuances sémantiques entre *solutionner* et *résoudre* ? Utiliserait-on de préférence l'un pour des problèmes mathématiques ou scientifiques, et l'autre pour des problèmes quotidiens ?

Est-ce qu'un de ces deux verbes est considéré comme plus soutenu que l'autre ?

Answer (score 3):

**Solutionner** est peut-être plus un [hispanisme](https://dle.rae.es/solucionar) qu'un anglicisme.

Ce verbe est encore généralement fustigé car il est plus long que son prédécesseur et est jugé "inélégant". Il en va de même avec les dérivés **soluble** et **solutionnable**.

Il a cependant l'avantage d'être plus régulier, dérivé logique de *solution*, et d'appartenir au 1<sup>er</sup> groupe. Après une pointe curieusement centrée autour de 1910, son usage progresse à nouveau mais reste très minoritaire.

[image]

Je déconseillerais l'emploi de *solutionner* tant qu'il n'a pas acquis ses lettres de noblesse.

Comment: Oui, _solutionner_ n'a pas vraiment de raison d'être puisque nous avons _résoudre_.

Comment: @Frank La langue a ses raisons que la raison ne connait pas...

Comment: Oui, oui, assurèment, et l'usage changera sans doute.

Answer (score 1):

> Voir [« Résoudre » ou « solutionner »](https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/regles-orthographe/resoudre-ou-solutionner/). Cela confirme, qu'étant
> donné la synonymie des deux mots, on évitera dans tous les cas d'utiliser
> « solutionner » à la place de « résoudre ». ([Graffito](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/8383/graffito))